# nodejs: release resources on http.createServer shutdown

Tags: node.js, resources, shutdown, application-shutdown

I developed a proxy server using node. I start the proxy with something like this (that is, I'm not using express, just plain http module):

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(config.port);
```

In the middle I iniatilize an sql server connection pool, and I'd like to make sure that when the server is shutdown (on purpose or due to some kind of exception) the pool is released and everything is cleaned up.

Which would be the correct way to ensure that some clean up function is executed when my server is shut down or when the node process is killed?

Answer (score 1):

You can have listeners on the set of events which can lead to your being terminated - `exit`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `uncaughtException`, `unhandledRejection`.

```
process.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);
  // Your cleanup code here
});
```